# How can I change which application is launched when I press the play button on my remote?

Tags: macos, remote-control

My mac mini came with a remote control. When I press the play button, iTunes is launched. How can I change what happens when I press this button (e.g. launch a different program)?

Comment: It's probably related to a LaunchAgent. Maybe I can find which.

Comment: The MENU button of the remote is controlled by com.apple.RemoteUI, but I can't find the one controlling the Play button.

Comment: @zneak: would rebinding the menu button also wake up the computer from sleep mode like the play button does?

Comment: I really don't know. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tool like [Remote Buddy](http://www.iospirit.com/products/remotebuddy/) might help here, but it's probably much more than you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

according to the writer : This seems to work with iTunes 8 and 9, although you'll need to redo the patch after upgrading.

Open a Terminal and type the following

```
cd /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS
sudo mv iTunes iTunesX
sudo curl http://www.cs.umd.edu/~dmonner/iTunes -O
sudo chmod uog+x iTunes enter code here
```

From http://www.cs.umd.edu/~dmonner/iTunes

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, os, subprocess

launch = True
blocker = ""

apps = ["Spotify", "Songbird"]

ps = subprocess.Popen("/bin/ps -x", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

for line in ps.stdout.read().split("\n"):
    for app in apps:
        if app in line:
            launch = False
            blocker = app

ps.stdout.close()

if launch :
    os.spawnvp(os.P_WAIT, '/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunesX', sys.argv)
else :
    print "Not launching iTunes while %s is running." % blocker
```

and you can read more [here](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2122639&start=30&tstart=0) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/31925/stop-play-pause-button-opening-itunes-in-snow-leopard).

Comment: That's a pretty dirty hack.