# Play/Pause buttons - different application?

Tags: itunes, keyboard, music

Given the age of [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/469/how-can-i-change-which-application-is-launched-when-i-press-the-play-button-on-m), and the fact that it's about the remote, I think there's merit in asking this again, and separately:

On a Mac keyboard the <kbd>F8</kbd> key is also a play/pause button. By default, it controls iTunes. I would like to use it to control another program (specifically Vox)

1. Is this possible?
2. Is it possible *without* third-party software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but not without third-party software or scripting.

You can use the [Vox preference pane](http://coppertino.com/vox/addon.html) to set this though:

[image: Vox Preferences]

(go to Vox → Preferences → Controls → Setup)

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! Great to get further away from iTunes.